# Erro código PHP

Tags: php, syntax-error

Boa noite! Desculpe, sei que deveria procurar aprender o PHP para sanar minhas dúvidas, mas creio que para resolver a duvida que tenho levaria muito tempo que nao tenho agora.

Estou descriptografando um código PHP e ele apresentou um erro na hora de executar.
Estou fazendo pelo Wamp e Usando um Virtual Host na máquina(Wamp).

Se puder me explicar o que aconteceu ficarei grato.
Segue o código:

${$kvdmeckplis}=explode(""email":{\"name":"",${${"GLOBALS"}["ekigfkpu"]});

Segue erro:
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'email'

Answer (score 0):

Para inicio, qual a sua finalidade neste código? Porque existem muitas aspas duplas, tipo isso ""email", o que deixa muito sem sentido. E o código esta dando erro porque o PHP esta tentando procurar alguma variavel chamada email, o certo não seria assim "email"?

Comment: Como eu falei no inicio meu nobre, eu pouco sei de PHP, estou descriptografando na esperança de que funcione. A informação que eu sei, é que, ele salva informações em um banco de dados.
Segue o código criptografado, talvez ajude:

${$kvdmeckplis}=explode("\x22\x62an\x6b\x22:{\"na\x6de\x22:\x22",${${"\x47LO\x42\x41\x4c\x53"}["\x65\x6b\x69\x67\x66\x6b\x70\x75"]});